# UDP Client Server Java

Tags: java, udp, client-server

I have simple UDP client and server codes. When the server gets the request from the client, I want to form a reply out of the data send by the client together with some additional data, as shown in the code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class UDPClient {

public static void main(String args[]){ 
    // args give message contents and destination hostname
    DatagramSocket aSocket = null;
    try {
        aSocket = new DatagramSocket();    
        byte [] m = args[0].getBytes();
        InetAddress aHost = InetAddress.getByName(args[1]);
        int serverPort = 8211;                                                       
        DatagramPacket request =
            new DatagramPacket(m,  args[0].length(), aHost, serverPort);
        aSocket.send(request);                                  
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
        DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);   
        aSocket.receive(reply);
        System.out.println("Reply: " + new String(reply.getData()));    
    }catch (SocketException e){System.out.println("Socket: " + e.getMessage());
    }catch (IOException e){System.out.println("IO: " + e.getMessage());
    }finally {if(aSocket != null) aSocket.close();}
}
```

}

public class UDPServer {

```
  public static void main(String args[]){ 
        DatagramSocket aSocket = null;
        try{
            aSocket = new DatagramSocket(8211);
                    // create socket at agreed port
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
            while(true){


                buffer = ("Hello "+new String(request.getData()).toUpperCase()+" Goodbye").getBytes();

                System.out.print("Replying to client: "+buffer);

                DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, 
                    request.getAddress(), request.getPort());
                aSocket.send(reply);
            }
        }catch (SocketException e){System.out.println("Socket: " + e.getMessage());
        }catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("IO: " + e.getMessage());
        }finally {if(aSocket != null) aSocket.close();}
    }
```

}

The problem is, that as an output I get: Replying to client: Hello PAUL and the same is received at the client side, with Goodbye being omitted. Why is it being omitted? Interestingly, if I do this:

```
buffer = ("Hello "+"Goodbye " +new String(request.getData()).toUpperCase()).getBytes();
```

the output is Hello Goodbye PAUL and the same is sent to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply invoking `new String(request.getData())` is dangerous. the `DatagramPacket` request isn't just going to be your string, it's going the entire packet. You should use the other methods provided by `DatagramPacket` to get the real data, before converting to a string.

```
byte[] packet = new byte[request.getLength()]; 
packet = Arrays.copyOfRange(request.getData(), request.getOffset(), request.getLength() + request.getOffset());

//packet now contains just the string portion of your request, use that instead
```

Comment: I've tried what you've said, and although I get a reply containing both hello and goodbye, the request.getData() is showing gibberish because it is not properly casted. That is the reason why new String(request.getData()) was used in the first place.

Comment: Yes, you still have to cast `packet`. All I did was extract the bytes you wanted from `request`. You shouldn't be casting `request` at all, since it's a `DatagramPacket`. If you try to force it to a string, you'll get unexpected behavior.